# Understanding PDO/SQL Query (and a few other questions)

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am not at all new to coding, but very new to PHP, PDO, and SQL—and am having a difficult time understanding the query structure. I have a table with rows and five columns. The first column (name) of the first row contains the value "Arty Fez".

```
<?php
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
$result = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY name ASC");
$result->execute;

echo $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

I create a PDO connection object, then prepare and execute a query. Then I fetch the (next??) row and try to echo the resulting array. This does not work and I'm not sure why. How can I access the data in a table?  I'm having a very difficult time understanding the idea behind this structure; everything seems so convoluted.

As a side-question, would anyone mind explaining the philosophy behind the way data-access is structured? I understand the benefits of organizing data in dynamic tables and referring to some more structured result-table, but actually accessing the data in said tables feels like exploring some unnecessarily cryptic query-labyrinth (but, I assume this is because I am missing some integral component to why it's done the way it is).

Eventually, I'm going to have a table with names/emails, and print said table out some html/php-incremental-loop table.

Comment: As a side note, if, when reading this, you feel it is deserving of a down-vote: It would help a lot more to toss in a comment as to why.

Comment: @Mike W Ah, apologies. I assumed the purpose last line of code was somewhat obvious, and "it does not work" meaning its not fulfilling that purpose: I would like to print the contents of the row in the specified table. (That is, the description of my problem was in the rest of the post.) And, no, a treatise would not be appropriate, but I've often read general structural principles summed up in a few sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use `$result->fetchAll()` to fetch all rows and you cannot echo an array, you need to use `print_r` to deal with arrays. Loop through it with a foreach loop. And catch errors using a `try catch` statement.

```
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
$result = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY name ASC");
try {
    $result->execute;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
print_r($result->fetchAll());
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Alright, excellent. Would you mind explaining why FETCH_ASSOC does not work in this case? I assumed it would return an array whose values I could call upon using the column name as an index (or would it work, but fetchAll would be a better solution because I'm eventually going to print out the whole row?)

Comment: Yeah you don't need FETCH_ASSOC, because fetchAll automatically returns a numeric array inside an associative array. So you should use two foreach loops (if that makes since)

Comment: No problem my friend!